# regular expression in ruby for a tag name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to allow the following characters in a regular expression:

```
a-z
A-Z
0-9
<space>
-
.
#
+
.
@
/
```

This is what I have so far although I have no idea if it's right. I feel like I'm doing it the wrong way:

```
  validates :name, :presence => true,
                 :length     => { :within  => 1..28},
                 :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
                 :format     => { :with => /[a-zA-Z\d\+\#\-\@\. ]+/ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the forward slash, and you can omit some of the backslashes as escaping is less needed in a character family:

```
/[a-zA-Z\d+#\-@. /]+/
```

should do.

Comment: it appears that works, although / needs to be escaped according to rubular. Thanks!

Comment: is this what i would do if i want to make sure they cant add new lines or other sneaky shit? `\A[a-zA-Z\d+#@. \/\-]+\Z`

Comment: / should be escaped and - should not (put it at the end of the char class)